# Generalised version of le Cam's Third Lemma

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, asymptotics, weak-convergence

I'm confused with the generalised version of Le Cam's Third lemma presented in Theorem 6.6 of van der Vaart asynptotics Statistics

here: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ocg2AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT188&lpg=PT188&dq=van+der+vaart+theorem+6.6&source=bl&ots=Rm4Rw_KJ8H&sig=iXbKRK_HhSX1qQhKjhlGOcLC7Nc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr1uCo2d7JAhUEJR4KHcx7CpoQ6AEIOTAE#v=onepage&q=van%20der%20vaart%20theorem%206.6&f=false

What does it mean saying that $L(B):=E(1_B(X)V)$ defines a probability measure? And how does the monotone convergence theorem help to show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that $L(B):=E\left(1_B(X)V\right)$ defines a probability measure means that $L(\emptyset)=0$ and that if $\left(B_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of measurable pairwise disjoint sets, then $$\tag{*}L\left(\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}B_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}L\left(B_n\right).$$ 
When the considered family is finite, this follows from linearity of expectation. For the general case, define $f_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbf 1_{B_j}(X)\cdot V$; in this way, $(f_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a non-decreasing sequence and (*) follows from the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Ok, I have some questions: provided that (1) $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{B_j}(X)V=\sum_{j=1}^\infty 1_{B_j}(X)V$ and (2) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \int 1_{B_j}(x) VdL= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \int 1_{B_j}(x) VdL$ then by the monotone convergence theorem we have (3) $ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \int 1_{B_j}(x) V dL=\int \sum_{j=1}^\infty 1_{B_j}(x)VdL $. How do we know that (1) and (2) hold, i.e. that the limits exist?

Comment: (1) is a pointwise convergence; check what happens if $x\in B_j$ for some $j$, and if $x$ is not in any $B_j$. (2) is just the definition of convergence of series (monotone convergence theorem also works if the limit is not integrable).

Comment: Regarding (2): I agree that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \int 1_{B_j}(x)VdL$ could be $\infty$ and the monotone convergence theorem still holds, but how do I know that the limit exists (finite or infinite)? Regarding (1), I thought it was the same story as (2), I don't get your point on pointwise convergence, sorry. Thanks a lot

Comment: For (1), you have a limit of a sequence of functions (say $(f_n)$) which converges to some $f$; in this context, it means that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for each $x$. In (2), the limit exists because you consider an non-decreasing sequence.